# C# Infinite Rainbow Background Loop

Tags: c#, loops, infinite

Why this infinite rainbow background loop is not working, I'm running this code in C# Forms and idea is to get background changing color after you clicked button1. I tried difference infinite loop makers like: for(;;). But here is the code:

```html
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    while (true)
    {
         this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
         this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
         this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
         this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
         this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
         this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
         this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
         this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
         this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Violet;
    }
```

thank you.

Comment: What is the type of application that you run this code on?

Comment: How does this "not working" manifest itself?

Comment: Where is this code run? in `OnPaint`?

Comment: Because rainbows are not infinite. They are caused by refraction of light from water. (In other words, you need to add more information - what kind of application are you building etc.)

Comment: You never give the UI time to show anything; Sleep pauses the UI thread as well.. Insert a `this.Refresh()` after each color change! - Btw, going from red to orange via darkred isn't likely. redorange would be more plausible, no?

Comment: If you have a recent version of C#, you can mark the function `async` and replace `Thread.Sleep` by `await Task.Wait`. (Though a naive implementation will get confused when the user clicks the button twice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is windows form, you can't do `Thread.Sleep(n)` because it Sleep's your Form, what you need is a `Timer`, a quick and dirty way to solve your problem

```
public List<Color> colors  = new List<Color> {
    Color.Red,
    Color.DarkRed,
    Color.Orange
};

private int current;
private Timer t = new Timer();
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    t.Interval = 250;
    t.Tick += T_Tick;

}

private void T_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    this.BackColor = colors[current++]; //change to rainbows other colors
    current %= colors.Count; // rainbow does not have infinite color, we should start again somewhere
}

*your_click_method* {
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but rainbow need to start after you clicked button1 like:  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//here code }

Answer (score 0):

Apart from this will surely look horrible,
your infinite loop will block the gui thread, so the gui will never be updated.
That means your programm has no time to apply the changed background color.

Supposing that you are using Windows Forms you should drop a timer to your form with an interval of 250ms. 
Then store your Colors in an array, list whatever and make it a member of that form...

```
private List<Color> rainbowColors = new List<Color>()
        {
          Color.Red,
          Color.DarkRed,
          ....
        };
```

You will also need an index to know which color you are currently showing.

```
private int rainbowIndex;
```

On your timer event do something like this:

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.BackColor = this.rainbowColors[this.rainbowIndex++];
  this.rainbowIndex = this.rainbowIndex % this.rainbowColors.Count;

  this.Invalidate(); //Really change the formcolor
}
```

So on each timer interval you will go one color further and reset it if the last color is shown.

Comment: I think you forgot to increment your index.

Comment: easier: `BackColor = rainbowColors[(rainbowIndex++) % rainbowColors.Count]`

Comment: True as well, thats a cleaner solution.

Comment: @Rotem yes it is one line but it will give exception when index passes `int.Max` will be negative.

Comment: @tetralobita well you could use `uint` with an `unchecked` expression, but yeah the way you did it in your answer is simpler and more readable.